# Invalid use of group function 1111

Tags: mysql, triggers

I keep getting an invalid use of group function. I'm looking to sum the values of one table and return the answer to the original table. I will be using this in a trigger.

But I keep getting an invalid use of group function 1111

```
UPDATE `Order`
INNER JOIN orderitem
ON order.OrderID = orderitem.OrderId
SET Order.TotalAmmount = SUM(orderitem.UnitPrice)
WHERE orderitem.OrderitemId = order.OrderId
```

Comment: Aggregate functions are only usable in SELECT queries/subqueries.

Answer (score 1):

Use a sub-query to aggregate:

```
UPDATE `Order`
SET `Order`.TotalAmmount = 
  (SELECT SUM(UnitPrice)
   FROM orderitem
   WHERE OrderitemId = `Order`.OrderId)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use an aggregated  result directly in a set value   (because the level of aggregation between the result and each row of the table is not the same)
you should  use an inner join on subquery for aggregated  result  and use the result for the subquery

```
    UPDATE `Order`
    INNER JOIN (
        select orderitemID, SUM(orderitem.UnitPrice) sum_price
        from orderitem 
        group by orderitemID
    )  t on t.orderitemID = order.OrderId 
    SET  Order.TotalAmmount = t.sum_price
```